# Using JavaScript to insert last updated date in HTML

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

Dreamweaver can generate the attached codes in JavaScript so that users can record the last updated date in a webpage.

The instruction works fine inside DW but it was skipped by most browsers as comments.

Placing the codes inside the "&lt script language = javascript &gt  ... &lt /script &gt" markup does not help.

Anoter unsuccessful thing that I have tried is just to strip off the comment signs. It seems the syntax/format is not correct.

Pls help.

`<!-- #BeginDate format:It1 -->14-10-2021<!-- #EndDate -->`

Comment: I have not heard about Dreamweaver in like 15 years.

Comment: What is this magical code you are using to output the timestamp?

Comment: That is not Javascript code, it's probably some kind of annotation of DW. Please explain what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @CristopherRosales and also epascarello I just want to put a time stamp on my webpage saying "my last update was on dd/mm/yyyy" automatically after each update.

Comment: Try this
<p>
<script> document.write(new Date().toLocaleDateString()); </script>
</p>

Comment: @CristopherRosales It works. Thanx. Would you like to put it as an answer (with some explanation on the syntax)?

Comment: `document.write(new Date().toLocaleDateString());` will insert the current date, not when the file was last updated.

Comment: @user1599011 I see. Any suggestion?

Comment: How many files? How often are they updated? Are you using a server-side language?

Comment: @user1599011 About 30 files. Each will be revised once bi-monthly. They are just in simple html. The  modified versions will be re-published via  wordpress.  The suggested codes can do the job but it would be better if there is an automated version.

Comment: What "suggested codes" do you plan to use at this point?

Comment: @user1599011 The codes that can record the updated date automatically will be more preferrable.